# Declaring a new point using Emgu CV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, visual-c++, emgucv

Hi I can't seem to be able to even declare a point in Emgu CV currently. I'm trying to declare a new point so that I can use that point as the center of a rectangle which I will show on each frame of a video feed so that the user can see the Region of Interest. In my header file I have

```
Emgu::CV::Point2D<int,int>^Center;
```

and in my Source file I have

```
Center = gcnew Emgu::CV::Point2D<int,int>(120, 160);
```

The error that I'm getting is

```
5>c:\users\admin\desktop\swir source code\hyperspectral\baotfis\BAOTFISInterface.h(88): error C2039: 'Point2D' : is not a member of 'Emgu::CV'
```

which confuses me because how is it NOT a member of Emgu::CV?

Am I missing a namespace or am I just declaring it wrong? I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express. Any and all help is greatly appreciated thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Point2D documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.4.0.0/html/594a2f5b-ee34-a879-c4ad-07c59929be43.htm), Point2D only takes 1 template argument for the datatype of the point.  You want:

```
Point2D<int>
```

Also, get rid of that '^' character - why is that even there?

Comment: It still gave me the same error. The '^' is there because it's a managed variable.

Comment: Ah, I was unfamiliar with the Microsoft C++ Component Extensions.  Without seeing your entire header file it's hard to know for sure why the compiler is complaining.

Comment: Are you sure you have the namespace correct?  Take a look at the library header file and make sure that CV isn't lower case or something weird like that.

Comment: Did you change both your .h and .cpp files with the Point2D<int> change?